# How to git ignore folder based on content

Tags: git, gitignore

Is it possible to ignore a full folder based on some criteria about it's content. For example I want to ignore everything in all folders that contain at least one html file. How can this be done? (If at all)

Comment: I don't think you can do that. git-ignore is based on file names. But if the content doesn't change then you could script to generate the .gitignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality in Git, and it doesn't make much sense to have it, anyway.

If you have some files in a directory you can easily inspect them to find out if there is any `.html` file amongst them. If there are many directories (with subdirectories) a simple command line can find the `.html` files and produce the needed rules to put in `.gitignore`.

If a `.html` file is created later in a directory that was not previously ignored, adding the directory path to `.gitignore` is not enough, you also have to remove the existing tracked files from the repo.

A simple command to get all `.html` files and produce the rules to put in `.gitignore`:

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec dirname \{\} \; | sort -u
```

It finds all the `.html` files from the current directory and its subdirectories and executes `dirname` for each of them. The output of `find` is then piped to `sort` that sorts them and removes the duplicates (`-u`).

*(I didn't test its output with Git, it might need small tweaking but this is the idea.)*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way in git.  However, you could run a script (python, etc.) that does the checking for you and then writes the gitignore on the folder.